# what is the first value returned by adam optimizer in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

i am using tensorflow to create a two layered DNN. i used AdamOptimizer as my optimizer.   below is my code

```
pred_raw = create_feedforward_nn_model(x, weights, biases)
pred = tf.round(tf.nn.sigmoid(pred_raw))
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=pred, logits=y))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

when i do `seession.run` on `train_op` it returns two values, i know that second value is the loss, but what is the first value here. I have seen many tutorials, but, in most of them they are ignoring the first value by using _ like as shown below

```
_,loss = sess.run([train_op, cost],={x: batch_features, y: batch_labels})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [mnist/mechanics](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/get_started/mnist/mechanics) under **Check the Status** you can find the following line:

> Since `train_op` is an Operation with no output value, the corresponding element in the returned tuple is None and, thus, discarded. However, the value of the loss tensor may become NaN if the model diverges during training, so we capture this value for logging.

Comment: Oh! mybad, i have been thinking it wrong here then. so, i gave two inputs to sess.run, which are train_op and cost, which returned values for each of them. and train_op was the return from adam optimizer. I was thinking that  adam optimizer give two different outputs! thanks